# Laravel: How to print out strings in an array within escaped controller text

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am setting a text block to email out and setting the $body variable.  The issue is that my `$app->reference_image_url` field is an array of strings so I get an `array to string conversion` error.  I tried a foreach loop to have each url string added but that threw an error.

```
       $body = <<<COMMENT
* Main Image
$app->image_url
$app->image_notes

* Reference Images

$app->reference_image_url
$app->reference_image_notes
COMMENT;

$this->send($body);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be formatted string (maybe with comma), then you can use php implode function.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

For your ease to refer, I attached a code block copied from the manual here:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```